# CodeIgniter: Removing "index.php" in URL on WAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, wamp, wampserver

In CodeIgniter, I want to remove the "index.php" in the URL, on my localhost (WAMP). For example, http://localhost.com/ci/index.php/controller/function to http://localhost.com/ci/controller/function

I have changed

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = '';
```

My .htaccess file (which is located in the root directory, where the index.php lies) is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /igniter

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404’s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have also gone into httpd.conf file and uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

And finally the directory section in the httpd.conf file looks like this..

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

And I still can't get it to work.. The page reads: "The requested URL /db/site was not found on this server."

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are right! Just had to set it to the correct directory. Thanks man.

Comment: Danny, if Alfonso solved your problem, you need to accept his answer so he can be rewarded for his time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteBase /
```

To change the directory

Comment: And if anyone is using alias, this one works: RewriteBase /aliasname