# Unable to Remove index.php on ExpressionEngine WAMP Installation

Tags: .htaccess, windows-7, wamp, expressionengine

I have WAMP v2.2 installed on my Windows 7 machine, with virtual hosts enabled.

I've successfully installed ExpressionEngine for one of my local sites, and everything works great except when I try to remove `index.php` from the URL using the [approved `.htaccess` method](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html). I still get a 404 error if `index.php` is not present, but the page displays fine with `index.php` in the URL.

I made sure the rewrite module was checked in the Apache menu:
[image: the rewrite module was checked in the Apache menu]. I've successfully used this method dozens of times on commercial hosts, so I'm stumped.

Update for pvledoux:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Removes index.php
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

  # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
  # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
</IfModule>
```

Note: I tried adding the `?` into the rule, but it didn't work.

The site is at the root of the Virtual Host.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your .htaccess? Is the site installed in a sub-folder?

Comment: Maybe `RewriteBase /` as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084223/codeigniter-removing-index-php-in-url-on-wamp

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got It!

I needed to add AllowOverride in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory "C:\Site\Root\Path">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow  
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

A gagillion thanks and a 6-pack of beer goes to @parhamr for helping me out of this pickle.

Comment: This worked for me with Vagrant and ExpressionEngine

Answer (score 1):

try to add  RewriteBase /

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase / 

  # Removes index.php
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

  # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
  # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
</IfModule>
```

and check for sure that mod_rewrite is active in phpinfo

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities here you could try out here:

```
[...]
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks
[...]
```

Or:

```
[...]
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews
[...]
```

Or:

```
[...]
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks
Options +MultiViews
[...]
```

From my experience, Apache when running on Windows often needs one or both of those in order to do these kinds of things correctly. It might also straight up 500 on you, but these have worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your default document in Apache?  If you are removing index.php physically from the machine and it reports a 404 on just a directory, www.domain.com/home/ that means Apache is looking for index.php still.

Comment: Hi Josh,

Are you saying I should remove index.php as the default document? I tried it and it had no effect. I also tried just commenting out the whole command but that didn't work either.

Comment: @kgrote Where are you setting the default document in Apache?  If you show what you are defaulting in Apache, we should be able to detect what the problem is.

Comment: Here's what the rule looked like by default:

    `<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
    </IfModule>`

And after I updated it:

    `<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php3 index.html index.htm
    </IfModule>`

The file is located in `C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apachex.xx.x/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: @kgrote And you are sure the dir_module is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Is [mod_rewrite turned on](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/check-enable-mod_rewrite-apache.html) in the Apache?